# How to access to a value of a scala Tuples

Tags: scala, tuples

I have a sequence of tuples that with a value and his power 2:

```
val fields3: Seq[(Int, Int)] = Seq((3, 9), (5, 25))
```

the thing that I want to know is if there is a way to access to a value of the same tuple directly when I create the object whithout use a foreach:

```
val fields3: Seq[(Int, Int)] = Seq((3, 3 * 3 ), (5, 5 * 5))
```

my idea is something like:

```
val fields3: Seq[(Int, Int)] = Seq((3, _1 * _1 ), (5, _1 * _1)) //like this doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Seq(2,3,4).map(i => (i, i*i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the tuple in a case class potentially:

```
case class TupleInt(base: Int) {
  val tuple: (Int, Int) = (base, base*base)
}
```

Then you could create the sequence like this:

```
val fields3: Seq[(Int, Int)] = Seq(TupleInt(3), TupleInt(5)).map(_.tuple)
```

I would prefer the answer @geek94 gave, this is too verbose for what you want to do.

An equally valid way to express this is:

```
val fields3: Seq[(Int, Int)] = Seq(3, 5).map(i => i -> i*i)
```